# Wrong calculation of font size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I tried to write a simple font size changer. That works perfectly until I use bootstrap framework.
When I increase the font size, the font size decreases. That's a strange behaviour.

```
var baseFontSize;

(function () {
    "use strict";

    /*  Global variables */ 



    /*  jQuery Plugin: convert fontsize of a DOM element to em
    *
    *   usage: $( element ).pxToEm()
    *   returns a number rounded to 3 digits
    *
    */
    $.fn.pxToEM = function () {
        var fontSize = this.css("font-size"),
            value = /[^em|pt|px]*/g.exec(fontSize);
        return Number((value / baseFontSize).toFixed(3));
    };

}(jQuery));



$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    var body = $("#bodyid"),
        increaser = $("#font-sizer > ul > li:first-child"),
        decreaser = $("#font-sizer > ul > li:last-child"),
        maxFontSize = 2.0,
        minFontSize = 0.5;

    baseFontSize = parseFloat(body.css("font-size"));

    increaser.click(function (event) {
        var actualFontSize = body.pxToEM();
        actualFontSize += 0.1;
        if (actualFontSize > maxFontSize) {
            actualFontSize = maxFontSize;
        }
        body.css("font-size", actualFontSize + "em");
    });

    decreaser.click(function (event) {
        var actualFontSize = body.pxToEM();
        actualFontSize -= 0.1;
        if (actualFontSize < minFontSize) {
            actualFontSize = minFontSize;
        }
        body.css("font-size", actualFontSize + "em");
    });

});
```

I have added a fiddle link with my code.

https://jsfiddle.net/uqrqo6bs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EM** as stated by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length):
This unit represents the calculated font-size of the element. If used on the font-size property itself, it represents the inherited font-size of the element.

This means that font-size in em for an element will depend on the font-size of its parent.

In your fiddle,

1. The body font-size is 14px
2. #bodyid font-size is 16px
3. To calculate #bodyid font-size, em needs to be calculated based on it's parent which in your example is"body". Your fiddled is using #bodyid for the base font-size. If you use 'body' instead, it should work just fine.

**Change required:**

```
baseFontSize = parseFloat(body.css("font-size"));
```

to

```
baseFontSize = parseFloat($('body').css("font-size"));
```

Answer (score 3):

you can set your default `font-size` to  `em`:

```
#bodyid {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/44fr6q6c/)**

Comment: Hey, this method will not work for values other than 1em. Try using 1.1em or 0.9em, the increase and decrease functions will show unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You are making the assumption that all the sizes used in the document are using the same unit. E.g. if the body has 1em and the font size of the element is 16 px, your function `pxToEm` will return 16(em).

You need to convert based on the element unit

Example for (px) to (em)

> 1em / 16px * (element font size in px) = resulting in em